# Meteor.js Tracker.autorun / Tracker.depend on exported variable from server-side with set interval

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-tracker

I'm trying to get my head around Meteor's Tracker.autorun and Tracker.dependancy features.

I'm trying to do something that seems simple in my mind but I'm struggling to execute.

I have a server-side function, that I register as a method:

```
let count = 0

setInterval(()=>{
    count ++
    return count
}, 1000)

export default count
```

Register as a method:

```
import count from './setIntervarl'

Meteor.methods({
    getData:function() {
      return count
    }
  });
```

And then call up on the client side:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'

import './main.html';

// Setup reactive variable
rv1 = new ReactiveVar(9)

Meteor.call('getData', function(error, results) {
  if(error){
          console.log("error:"+error);
      } else {
      rv1.set(results)
      }
});

// Display the output from reactiveVar
Template.someData.helpers({
  someData: function() {
    return rv1.get();
  }
})
```

Can someone please show me how to use Tracker.autorun or Tracker.dependancy so that my UI updates with interval that is set in my server-side function

I'm having really trouble getting this working.

Many thanks

Comment: is this issue resolved? If so, please mark the answer as accepted or comment if there is still a problem remaining.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no reactivity out of the box here. Meteor methods are not reactive but just a wrapped ddp call to a server (rpc-) endpoint that returns something.

In order to gain reactive data from the server, you need to subscribe to a publication. If you want only this counter being published, you may create a collection with a single document and publish it.

*imports/CountCollection.js (both)*

```js
export const CountCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCounter')
```

*server/counter.js (server)*

```js
import { CountCollection } from '../imports/CountCollection'


let counterDocId

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // optional: clear the collection on a new startup
  // this is up to your use case
  // CountCollection.remove({})

  // create a new counter document
  counterDocId = CountCollection.insert({ count: 0 })

  // use the Meteor.setInterval method in order to
  // keep the Meteor environment bound to the execution context
  // then update the counter doc each second
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    CountCollection.update(counterDocId, { $inc: { count: 1 } })
  }, 1000)
})

// Now we need a publication for the counter doc. 
// You can use the `limit` projection to restrict this to a single document:
Meteor.publish('counterDoc', function () {
  if (!counterDocId) this.ready()
  return CountCollection.find({ _id: counterDocId }, { limit: 1 })
})
```

Now you can subscribe to this publication and get reactive updates to the document:

*client/someData.js (client)*

```js
import { CountCollection } from '../imports/CountCollection'


import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'

import './main.html';

// Setup reactive variable
const reactiveCounter = new ReactiveVar(0)
const counterSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('counterDoc')

Template.someData.onCreated(() => {
  const instance = this

  instance.autorun(() => {
    // counterSubscription.ready() will re-called
    // when the publication released a new cursor
    // which causes the autorun to re-run = reactivity
    if (counterSubscription.ready()) {
      // there is only 1 doc published, so no query require
      const counterDoc = CountCollection.findOne() 
      reactiveCounter.set(counterDoc && counterDoc.count)
    }
  })
})

// Display the output from reactiveVar
Template.someData.helpers({
  someData: function() {
    return reactiveCounter.get()
  }
})
```

**Sidenote:**

don't forget to get the paths and imports correct

**Readings:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setInterval